# Not able to add Objective C Bridging Header in Swift project

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, objc-bridging-header

I am using Xcode 8.2.1 and Swift 3. I am trying to add Objective C Bridging Header. Though I have created the .h file there is no row in the Build Settings to add the Bridging Header 
[image: Weird Issue]

I am stuck on this for hours. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In general, when I create a "CocoaTouch class", I am always asked if I want to create a bridging header and usually it's the simplest method even if I don't want to really create an Obj-C class.

Answer (score 0):

It takes really stupidity to make this mistake. So basically I created .h file before creating a .m file. Create a dummy .m file, and Xcode asks if you want to create an Objective C Header. Create .m first before creating .h

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have the `Basic` option selected (at the top right of you screenshot), select the `All` option and the setting you need will appear.

It will be easier to see if you search for `bridging` instead.